# ADFS 4.0 Windows 10 1703 SSO

Tags: windows-10, single-sign-on, adfs

We have recently updated most of our clients to windows 10 1703 and updated ADFS from 3.0 to 4.0 via farm migration. Any client running Windows 7 or 10 1607 still works as expected and external access still works as expected. Farm level is correct, fallback is enabled, kmsi is set. I'm starting to run out of ideas.

- Our setup is 4 local DC's
- 0 Azure DC's
- 2 ADFS servers, 1 primary 1 secondary
- 1 Ubunutu Web server running simplesaml

**What works:**

- Windows 7 and Windows 10 1603

  - SSO
  - Chrome, IE (Edge untested)
  - ADFS manual login via a form

**What doesn't work**

- Windows 10 1703

  - SSO
  - Chrome, IE, Edge

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated

Comment: well, it was working, after fiddling (and reverting everything) its now the same situation for all systems, no SSO

Comment: We worked some magic, got it working but found a single setting causing issues for some users. We think its permission based on something and its to do with trusted sites for specific users which prevent it working correctly.